# How to change the contents of an AngularJS view at runtime?

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

Inside an AngularJS controller I do a $http.post() request and update $scope with new data which works fine.

But in case of an error, I want to change the template of the same controller to another one. I haven't figured out how to change the template of a controller.

Here is some pseudo code inside the controller:

```
    // this is the controller
    var self = this

    $http
        .post('/something', $scope.something)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.result = data 
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            $scope.error = err
            var statusCode = err.statusCode
            // for example on a 403, I want the template 'errors/403.html' to 
            // be rendered
            self.template = $templateCache.get('errors/' + statusCode + '.html')
        })
```

Any ideas how this is possible? I do not want to put '/errors/403' to the routing because it is not idempotent.

Thanks for any suggestions. I am a bit desperate here ...

Comment: Are your controller configured in `$routeProvider` or just a plain `ng-controller`?

Comment: Yes, my controllers are configured in $routeProvider

Comment: There is a way to change the template like you want, but the values in `$scope` will not persist. You have to store the `$scope.error` in another place like `$rootScope` or a service anyway.

Comment: Tell me more about it @runTarm - how can I change the template inside a controller?

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
 $location.path('/login');
```

Comment: I do not see how this helps. How can I change the template inside a controller?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should setup the route provider and use then use $location service to change the URL.

configure route provider :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/error", { controller: "", templateUrl: "/app/error.html" });
// setup some more routes here as above
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/login" });
```

And in JS file -

```
var self = this
$http
.post('/something', $scope.something)
.success(function(data) {
$scope.result = data 
})
.error(function(err) {
$scope.error = err
var statusCode = err.statusCode
// for example on a 403, I want the template 'errors/403.html' to 
// be rendered
$location.path("/error");
})
```

Don't forget to add the angular-route.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
<div data-ng-view=""></div>

<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking of this but there are dynamic contents I want to apply to the error page. For example `$scope.error = err` hence I believe putting the error page to the `$routeProvider` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives'], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

```
var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function (scope, $q) {

    function success(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function error(response) {
        var status = response.status;

        if (status == 401) {
            window.location = "./index.html";
            return;
        }
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject(response);

    }

    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }

}];
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Comment: I am sorry I cannot follow you. Can you expand on that? And I do not want to use promises if possible.